# Can't narrow type of object after condition in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I get an error:

```
Property 'ip' does not exist on type 'IpDetails | Error'.
  Property 'ip' does not exist on type 'Error'.ts(2339)
```

Even if I checked the type by `("message" in res)` or used `isError` to narrow the type. Am I doing something wrong or is it TypeScript's bug?

```ts
interface IpDetails {
    ip : string,
}

interface Error {
    error: {
        code : number,
        message: string,
    },
}

let collection: IpDetails[] = [];

function isError(res: any | Error): res is Error {
    return (res as Error).error !== undefined;
}

const getIpData = async (ipAddress: string, config: any = {}): Promise<IpDetails|Error> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolve({ip : '1.1.1.1'});
  });
}

(async () => {
    let res = await getIpData('1.1.1.1');

    if (!isError(res)) { // if ('error' in res)
        let dublicate = collection.find(entry => entry.ip === res.ip); // <--- ERROR
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
collection.find(entry => entry.ip === res.ip);
```

When you have code in a callback function, typescript does not know when that function is going to be called. You and i know that the `.find` callback is called synchronously, but the type information can not indicate that. So typescript has to assume the worst case: that this code could be called at some arbitrary point in the future (like what happens with setTimeout). This means the check you just did for `isError` may no longer be accurate, because some piece of code may have reassigned `res` in the meantime.

The simplest way to fix this is to make `res` a const. That way, typescript can be sure that if the check was accurate at one point, it will always be accurate.

```
(async () => {
    const res = await getIpData('1.1.1.1');

    if (!isError(res)) {
        let dublicate = collection.find(entry => entry.ip === res.ip); 
    }
})();
```

Comment: Wow, that's very subtle! Thanks!